# Why doesn't it print the full character array?

Tags: c, arduino-uno

This is my first post so please bear with me.  Let me start with the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char inp[80], cmd[80];
char address[80],value[80];
boolean stringComplete = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}  

void loop() {
  serialEvent();
  if (stringComplete) {
    parse_cmd(inp);

    Serial.println(cmd);delay(1000);
    Serial.println(address);delay(1000);
    Serial.println(value);delay(1000);

    memset(inp, 0, strlen(inp));
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  int i=0;
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    inp[i] = inChar;delay(250);
    if (inChar == ';') {stringComplete = true;}
  i++;
  }
}

void parse_cmd(char *string){
  int i=0,j=0;
  for (i;i<strlen(string);i++) {
    if (string[i]==';' || string[i]==' ') break;
    else cmd[i] = string[i];      
  }
  i++;j=0;
  for (i;i<strlen(string);i++) {
    if (string[i]==';' || string[i]==' ') break;
    else address[j] = string[i];  
  }
  i++;j=0;
  for (i;i<strlen(string);i++) {
    if (string[i]==';' || string[i]==' ') break;
    else value[j] = string[i];
  }  
}
```

The program takes a string of three words, and creates three separate character arrays.

The problem is that when i try to print the three char variables, for some reason only 1 of them prints ok.

Say I input: 1234 5678 90;
I expect to see in return:
1234
5678
90

Instead i get:
1234
8
0

Only the last character prints for the second and third word.

The codes does exactly the same thing for the three words, so I cant understand why the 2nd and 3rd print wrong.

Many thanks,

MR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing j when loading the buffers for address and value.

Note that your input routine (serialEvent) also will not stop if there is too much data and will overrun your buffer.

Comment: No problem! Keep coding!